# Ignite tomee-webprofile-7.1.0-> Start error reporting at Tomee

Tags: ignite, apache-tomee

```
[1 image description here][1][2 image description here][2]
```

[3 image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqm2t.jpg)Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: 1
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: TomEEWebappClassLoader
      context: chinawork
      delegate: false

```
   [16:27:05] ver. 2.7.0#20181201-sha1:256ae401
[16:27:05] 2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[16:27:05] 
[16:27:05] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[16:27:05] 
[16:27:05] Quiet mode.
[16:27:05]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
[16:27:05]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[16:27:05] 
[16:27:05] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[16:27:05] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_152-b16 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.152-b16
[16:27:05] Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
[16:27:05] Initial heap size is 126MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
[16:27:05] Configured plugins:
[16:27:05]   ^-- None
[16:27:05] 
[16:27:05] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED]]]]
[16:27:06] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[16:27:06] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[16:27:07] REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
十二月 11, 2018 4:27:13 下午 org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
严重: Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: 1
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: TomEEWebappClassLoader
  context: cnf-soa
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@f6f4d33

    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:147)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:161)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:280)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalGridData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:123)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.onExchange(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2006)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processNodeAddFinishedMessage(ClientImpl.java:2181)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processDiscoveryMessage(ClientImpl.java:2060)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1905)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 201306200821, local class serialVersionUID = 201405
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:687)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1880)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1880)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2282)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2206)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1409)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2173)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2282)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2206)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:139)
    ... 12 more
[16:27:14] Performance suggestions for grid 'igniteCosco' (fix if possible)
[16:27:14] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[16:27:14]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[16:27:14]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[16:27:14]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[16:27:14]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[16:27:14] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[16:27:14] 
[16:27:14] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[16:27:14] 
[16:27:14] Ignite node started OK (id=9d93bb08, instance name=igniteCosco)
[16:27:14] Topology snapshot [ver=2, locNode=9d93bb08, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=3.1GB, heap=7.1GB]
十二月 11, 2018 4:27:15 下午 org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
严重: Failed to send message: TcpDiscoveryClientMetricsUpdateMessage [super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=null, id=1ac606c9761-9d93bb08-2ba3-4234-807b-941605b3597b, verifierNodeId=null, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=true]]
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getSendBufferSize(Socket.java:1215)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.socketStream(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1480)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.writeToSocket(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1606)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$SocketWriter.body(ClientImpl.java:1362)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
十二月 11, 2018 4:27:25 下午 org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
严重: Failed to reconnect to cluster (consider increasing 'networkTimeout' configuration property) [networkTimeout=5000]
2018-12-11 16:27:25.768 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR cjf.web.CommonServlet - 加载初始化资源文件[/cjf/config/cjfinit.properties]失败.
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Failed to execute dynamic cache change request, client node disconnected.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1337)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.getOrCreateCache(IgniteKernal.java:3310)
    at cjf.init.InitIgniteCache.intercept(InitIgniteCache.java:148)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.CjfClusterInterceptor.intercept(CjfClusterInterceptor.java:37)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.CjfMailInterceptor.intercept(CjfMailInterceptor.java:34)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.InitSsoInterceptor.intercept(InitSsoInterceptor.java:52)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.InitServletInterceptor.intercept(InitServletInterceptor.java:33)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.InitCjfInterceptor.intercept(InitCjfInterceptor.java:50)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.init.SysCacheInterceptor.intercept(SysCacheInterceptor.java:129)
    at cjf.common.responsibility.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:26)
    at cjf.web.CommonServlet.initCaches(CommonServlet.java:111)
    at cjf.web.CommonServlet.init(CommonServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteClientDisconnectedException: Failed to execute dynamic cache change request, client node disconnected.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$15.apply(IgniteUtils.java:948)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$15.apply(IgniteUtils.java:944)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteClientDisconnectedCheckedException: Failed to execute dynamic cache change request, client node disconnected.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onDisconnected(GridCacheProcessor.java:1173)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.onDisconnected(IgniteKernal.java:3949)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.onDiscovery0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$4.lambda$onDiscovery$0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:604)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body0(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2667)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$DiscoveryMessageNotifierWorker.body(GridDiscoveryManager.java:2705)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

[1 image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lf5A.jpg)   [2 image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZyME.jpg)
   [3 image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqm2t.jpg)

IgniteConfiguration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="igniteTest"/>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
          <property name="addresses">
          <list>
             <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47510</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                 </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What are you trying to do? What have you tried? A stack trace really isn't enough for anyone to help.

Comment: add image Look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

TomEE has lib/javaee-api-7.0-1.jar library that contains javax-cache version 1.1 while Ignite depends on javax-cache 1.0.
You need to eliminate this dependency issue.It makes sense to exclude java-cache  by setting openejb.classloader.forced-skip=javax.cache in system.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have put some type in Discovery data which is not present on other nodes.

I can see that you have "local class incompatible". Is it possible that you jave javax-cache 1.0 on one node but javax-cache 1.1 on another? It could cause the problem that you are observing.

Comment: It's javax-cache 1.1, the problem still exists

Comment: 201306200821 is JCache 1.0, so it seems that different nodes has different version of this library.